# NoMethodError in Categories#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi im new to ruby and cant figure out why nil is being passed to my `@category`

heres the controller

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

    def show
        @cateogry = Category.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
    end

    def create
      @category = Category.new(category_params)

      @category.save
      redirect_to @category
    end

    private
      def category_params
        params.require(:category).permit(:name_en, :name_ar, :thumb_url, :pano_url, :isactive)
      end
end
```

and the show.html.erb

```
<p>
  <strong>Name: (english)</strong>
  <%= @category.name_en %>
</p>
```

and i keep getting a

> NoMethodError in Categories#show undefined method `name_en' for
>   nil:NilClass

I have been stuck on this for a day and a half now and cant find a solution any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You mispelled category as instance variable here

```
def show
    **@cateogry** = Category.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: sometimes staring at code for ages does that to you.. sorry to post over a typo

Answer (score 0):

Updated code, Nothing wrong just typo mistake

```
def show
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
end

def new
end

def create
  @category = Category.new(category_params)

  @category.save
  redirect_to @category
end

private
  def category_params
    params.require(:category).permit(:name_en, :name_ar, :thumb_url, :pano_url, :isactive)
  end
```